# Shortcut to switch project and editor in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I often need to edit some code (in editor) and then work in the project structure. I would like switch between these two using the keyboard instead the mouse. How can I do that in PyCharm ?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard.pdf you'll find PyCharm default keymap in the pdf format. You can also access it from PyCharm by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice and then typing `keymap` and choosing *Default Keymap Reference*. In the keymap you see the following two entries:

- <kbd>F12</kbd> Go back to previous tool window
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> Go to editor (from tool window)

So once you are in the *Project* tool window (which you can open with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> shortcut) you can switch to editor by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and back to the *Project* window by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.

The shortcut described above as *Go back to previous tool window* is called *Jump to Last Tool Window* in the Settings/Keymap.
The shortcut descried above as *Go to editor* seems to be absent from Settings/Keymap so can't be customized.